# Force SSL and WWW together using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I'm trying to run my entire site through https and force www.

I've seen a number of solutions that provide forcing either www or https, and even a few combined, but I can't seem to get any to work. I usually find myself in a redirect loop.

The closest I've got is the following, but it's not close enough yet:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I need `https://www.example.com/`

`http://example.com SUCCESS`
`https://example.com SUCCESS`
`http://www.example.com FAIL`
`https://www.example.com SUCCESS`, although there's no actual redirection.

Thanks

**Update**
The following code successfully performs the redirection I require:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: If you have found a solution as your update suggests, please post it as an answer yourself and accept it. Helps maintain the Q&A nature of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forcing https and www is done by a combination of other provided answers.

This seems to work:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition instead, it should force the site into ssl for your domain

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This forces SSL but doesn't force the www. I've used a combination of your rule with another to successfully redirect how I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `[OR]` flag to your conditions. You really want *either* no www *or* no https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That does work, the resulting URL is what I want, although I see the redirect loop message - not the site.

Comment: @JasonVarga not sure why this would cause a redirect loop when the original rules didn't