# Force SSL and www in URL of Angular 5 application using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, angular5

I have an Angular 5 based website and I need to implement Force SSL with www in this website.
So basically I need any variation of domain like http://example.com or example.com or www.example.com etc.. all to redirect at https://www.example.com

The current used .htaccess files is as follows :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

I tried solutions from multiple resources, example of one such is  [Force SSL and WWW together using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11766995/6705117), by adding the mentioned code at the bottom of above code, but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: tried adding it at the bottom of .htaccess, but not working.

Comment: Not at the bottom. This should be as first to reditect to https

Comment: ok thanks, by putting it on top now the website is getting redirected to https, but still example.com variation remains the same but on https now. It should also go to https://www.example.com

Comment: Also, why putting it at top worked, not at the bottom ?

Comment: Change example.com to Your domain. This doesn't work at the bottom because this file is read line by line and if in some line will be Last line declaration this never be read

Comment: I obviously replaced example.com with my domain. but its still the same. Thanks for clarifying the position thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```